# Is my device's acceleromoter working as it should?

Tags: applications, sensors, gyroscope

I recently installed Asphalt Nitro, a racing app that supports using the device's "gyroscope" for steering. My device being as cheap as it is, it doesn't have a gyroscope, so I assume Asphalt is using the accelerometer. However, it seems to use the wrong axis. (I have to tilt it back and forth to steer.)

My question is, is it the app's fault or my tablet's fault?

Here's some test data (assuming horizontal is right-side up, data given in m/s²):

```
Right-side up:      X=0    Y=9.8  Z=0
Left:               X=9.8  Y=0    Z=0
Right:              X=-9.8 Y=0    Z=0
Upside down:        X=0    Y=-9.8 Z=0
Flat on the ground: X=0    Y=0    Z=9.8
```

Comment: They all look okay to me

Comment: What do you mean it uses the wrong axis? Isn't tilting back and forth how you're supposed to steer?

Comment: @EvanChen When I said tilting back and forth, I meant if I am facing the device, i.e. the axis around which I would rotate it to turn it upside down so that the back would face me. It *should* work by steering as I tilt it from side to side.